# How is config.json found by ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Presumably everything an ASP.NET 5 web site needs to run gets put under wwwroot.  Yet when I look at this dir when the site is running I don't see config.json.  So the question is, how does my web site startup code find config.json if it isn't under wwwroot?

A related question, if I want to create my own config file (since config.json only handles simple name/value pairs), would I put it next to config.json in my project or under wwwroot in order to be able to read the contents at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's in the wwwroot folder represents everything accessible to your site from HTTP. You can access your config files at runtime, but you can't make web requests for them (since they're not in wwwroot).

ASP.NET finds the root config.json in the Startup class:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var configuration = new Configuration()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional:   true);
```

Comment: So if the file is not under wwwroot how can it be accessed at runtime?  I get that the file is available when running from VS. But if I publish to an IIS server - only the stuff under wwwroot goes, right?  And if config.json is not under wwwroot, how does the published site find the file? Sorry, still a bit confused on this.

Comment: @KeithHill : The stuff under `wwwroot` is used to serve static files, for example, if you have any javascript files in there, then when the browser requests for these files, they are served from this folder, but you cannot access files (example: HomeController.cs, Startup.cs and config.json) directly from the browser. `Config.json` is supposed to be used by the server application itself and is of no significance to the end client.

Comment: @KeithHill, I'm still wrapping my head around it too, afaik the published site finds the file from depencency injection - http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html#the-wwwroot-folder    (side note: I think they went a little overboard with all the .json files, and the differences between some of them can be confusing, however they're still working on it so maybe it will improve).

Comment: @proggrock it would be of great help if you could help me out on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660383/file-not-found-exception-visual-studio-2015/38660566?)