# File Not Found Exception Visual Studio 2015

Tags: json, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting file not found error though I have the needed file inside the project directory.There are no compilation errors.

Here is my startup.cs class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace OdeToFood
{
public class Startup
{
    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile("config.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            var message = Configuration["greeting"];
            await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
        });
    }
}
}
```

And this is the error message I get when I build it.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'config.json' was not found and is not optional.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at OdeToFood.Startup..ctor()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.StartupLoader.LoadMethods(IServiceProvider services, Type startupType, String environmentName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__1(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Screenshot showing the file present

[image: json file]

How should I rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to use `Server.MapPath` function.
You can edit your `Constructor` with following code :

```
    public Startup()
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .AddJsonFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/config.json"));
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I am getting 'HTTPContext' doesn't contain a definition of 'Content' error

Comment: try this : `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/config.json")`

Comment: and where you are using `Content` ?

Comment: `the type or namespace web doesn't exist in the namespace "System" `- I am getting this now. What is `Content`?

Comment: which language you are using in Visual Studio is it C# ?

Comment: I am using C# language

Comment: Go to `references` folder and add new `reference` that is `System.Web`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118642/discussion-between-re3el-and-sunil-kumar).

Comment: The question is about ASP.NET Core, but the answer is about ASP.NET 4.x, so it won't work.